# Why did a scalar function lose performance after upgrading SQL Server from 2008 R2 to 2017?

Tags: sql-server

I have a scalar function that looks up a value in a table in another database, essentially turning a code into a name, where all of the codes are stored in a central location. For example, in Louisiana a code "02" translates to "Allen Parish", and in New Jersey a code "32" translates to "Transportation Equipment".

It wasn't great, but it wasn't terrible, and then I upgraded our SQL Servers from 2008 R2 to 2017, and suddenly the performance dropped off a cliff. I'm switching them to a replacement table-valued function, but I'm curious why the performance would drop so drastically. Did I miss a step when I moved the databases onto the new server (I did a detatch/move/attach)? Recompile? Burn an eye of newt atop the server at midnight?

Comment: First thing is to try and compare the plans from the old system and the new slower system to see if there's anything obvious there. I'm assuming the "other database" is on the same server, yes? Or are you doing a cross-server look-up?

Comment: Same server. I'll take a look...

Comment: Execution plans are identical.

Comment: So when you say it fell off a cliff, can you reproduce that side-by-side on those same systems you got the plans from? And from what to what? (2 seconds to 20 seconds? Order of magnitude stuff?)  Do you see any difference if you drop and re-create the function on 2017? How about if you drop/re-create it WITH SCHEMABINDING? Or WITH RECOMPILE? Just curious and throwing stuff out there to try and narrow this down.

Comment: Your real problem of course is using a scalar valued function.......

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you've become another victim of the revised Cardinality Estimator (CE) that was introduced in SQL Server 2014. I got hit by it last year, migrating from 2008 R2 to 2016.

A quick check/fix is to run the following against your database

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = ON
```

This will force your database to use the SQL Server 2008 R2 CE instead of the new one.

If it doesn't fix things, just set it back to OFF.

If it does fix your problem and you just have a few poorly performing queries, you can leave the legacy setting OFF, and add a flag to the individual queries that don't like it, by using

```
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 9481)
```

e.g.

```
SELECT OrderID, CreatedDate
FROM StockOrders
WHERE CreatedDate > '2018-01-31'
OPTION ( QUERYTRACEON 9481 );
```

[see here for more MS docn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/04/27/using-db-compatibility-level-130-with-old-ce-in-sql-server-2016/)

[Here's an explanation about flag 9481](https://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-2014-trace-flags-9481/)